# Objective-C RTMP connection

Tags: objective-c, xcode, rtmp

I am looking to make an app that would send data to an RTMP server, however I am looking to write my own code to connect but I can not seem to find the right class to use.  NSURLConnection I don't think is capable of connecting to a rtmp server.  Mainly I am asking if anyone could link me either some example code or some reading or point me in the right class to use to make a rtmp connection.

Thanks!
     Charlie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least two ways to connect to an RTMP server in Objective-C :

- You can try the [rtmp-wrapper](https://github.com/ifactorylab/rtmp-wrapper), it uses the library [librtmp](https://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/)
- Or you can try to build an AIR extension that implements a connection to the RTMP Server and communicate with it, here is explanation on how to do this : http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/transferring-data-ane-ios-pt1.html,

I hope it will help. Tell us if you succeed connecting to the RTMP server, I think your feedback could be interesting!

Comment: interesting, Thanks for the links I am surprised that there is not some class that I could just use that is made by apple.  Or use NSInputStream and NSOutputStream for it.  I definitely link what I got when I got something working.